# How to create apache Alias ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apache2

I have installed the LAMP on my Ubuntu 12.10. All are working correctly.

But I want to create a alias like **phpmyadmin**

I have created the folder root

```
/home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/
```

And added the following lines in my apache2.conf file

```
Alias /dropbox " /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/"
<Directory " /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I access it like `localhost/dropbox`, I received `403` Error Message. `Permission Not Denaid`. How can I fix this easily

Answer (score 2):

Did you restart the server afterwards?

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Check [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1843307) out too on Ubuntu forums. It looks like a similar problem to yours and is easily fixed.

Comment: I did that. But not working even i restarted the pc

Answer (score 2):

Is `/home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/` accessible to the `www-data` user?  To find out for sure, drop to a Terminal, `sudo -u www-data -s` to become the www-data user, and `cd /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/`.  If you can't get to the directory as www-data, neither can Apache.  `exit` to become root again, and `chmod` and/or `chown` your way out of the problem as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you include a trailing to the end of tour URL path, put one at the end of your alias name too (so this trailing will be required in the URL).

Restart apache2

You surelly have to change the owner group of your new directory to www-data :

```
sudo chown -R yourname:www-data /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www
```

And change file permissions like this :

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www
```

*...just learned...*

Add this into your Directory section :

```
Require all granted
```

**And now it works for me.**

Hope this will help.

Comment: This solved my problem. And without adding "Require all granted" to the config file it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
Alias /dropbox " /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/"
```

And:

```
<Directory " /home/user/Dropbox/Development/www/">
```

This raises the question: *why do you have a leading space inside the quotes?*

An absolute path with a leading space before `/` is generally not valid. For example:

```
$ ls -ld "/home" " /home"
ls: cannot access  /home: No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 15 23:53 /home
```

So, assuming the leading space is not intentional but an error, **try removing it and see if that fixes the problem.**